# Can I go to Pakistan with two months' expiry date on my passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, uk-citizens, pakistan

I'm British and don't need a visa for Pakistan as I have a valid NADRA card. I am coming back within passport validity time as I have return ticket.

Comment: What citizenship do you hold?

Comment: British and have pakistani NADDRA card (which I don't require visa for Pakistan).

Answer (score 2):

For Pakistan, British passports simply need to be valid for the period of intended stay. For those needing a visa the embassies (as opposed to Pakistani immigration) have stricter requirements, but for you only the rules of Pakistani immigration apply. And they only require it to be valid for the perod of stay.

Comment: Thanks a lot Craydre, is there any reference of this information? Regards. Ehsan

Comment: The Timatic database, what the Airlines use when deciding whether to let a passenger board a plane to a given destination, based on their nationality

Comment: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=GB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=PK&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C

Comment: By the way, what Card is it that you hold? It says holders of Pakistan Origin Cards (POC) and National Identity Cards for Overseas Pakistanis (NICOP) do not Need a visa.

Comment: Alright. Yeah, you'll be fine as Long as the passport is valid

Comment: Yes is valid for the period of my stay.

Comment: @Ehsan If this answer is satisfactory, feel free to "accept" it by clicking the green tick mark to the left. Thanks!